# Strange result with floating point addition

Tags: javascript

Why is it when I print/display the result of

```
eval("11.05") + eval("-11")
```

it comes out as 0.05000000000000071 instead of the expected 0.05. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This is not a `eval` issue, its due to floating point arithmetic. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `eval`. In fact, this is what happens if you type in a console `11.05 - 11`:
[image]

This is a consequence of how programming languages store floating-point numbers; they include a small error. If you want to read more about this, [check this out](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `eval` (which you should avoid).

You get the same problem with `11.05 - 11`.

This is just the usual [floating point problem](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, this is a floating point problem and has nothing to do with `eval`. Now for `eval`: you can easy avoid it here, using:

```
Number("11.05") + Number("-11");
```

To avoid the faulty outcome you could use `toPrecision`:

```
(Number("11.05") + Number("-11")).toPrecision(12);
// or if you want 0.05 to be the outcome
(Number("11.05") + Number("-11")).toPrecision(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `eval` is absolutely innocent here. The culprit is floating-point operation. If you do not expect a large number of numbers after the decimal, you may limit. But you can not avoid it.