# Javascript math imprecision error? (0.1+0.01+0.01+0.01+0.01+0.01 == 0.15000000000000002)

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript's Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)
>   [Strange result with floating point addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339606/strange-result-with-floating-point-addition)

Some simple JavaScript calculations in Safari 5.0.6  but the same phenomenon in Firefox:

```
var i=0.1;
i=i+0.01;       //= 0.11
i=i+0.01;       //= 0.12
i=i+0.01;       //= 0.13
i=i+0.01;       //= 0.14
i=i+0.01;       // expected == 0.15
console.log(i); // == 0.15000000000000002
```

**Where does this imprecision come from?**

Sure, I can handle it with `i.toPrecision()` or other methods, but does it have to be like that? Is this a floating-point rounding error?

The same happens in this example:

```
var i=0.14+0.01; //expected == 0.15
console.log(i);  //== 0.15000000000000002
```

**What is happening between 0.14 and 0.15?**

```
var i=0.1400001+0.01; //expected==0.1500001
console.log(i);       //== 0.1500001 ok!
```

and

```
var i=0.14000001+0.01; //expected==0.15000001 !! 
console.log(i);        //== 0.15000001000000002
```

What do I have to do differently to get the correct results?

Comment: Welcome to the world of representing floating point numbers in binary.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html so it is a problem made by storing the data to calculate in bits 'n bites?

Comment: You can reproduce a similar effect more concisely with `0.1 + 0.2`, which results in `0.30000000000000004`.

Comment: Alex has a good link, but essentially it is because binary cannot represent all floating points from base10. 0.1 is actually one such number you can't represent correctly in binary.

Comment: @birryree It's not related to binary. It's just that you only have a very little amount of information that you can store. Whether that is decimal or binary or whatever makes no matter.

Comment: Me: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` Javascript: `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're just floating point errors.

Work with integers, multiply everything you're doing by 10 * numbers of precision you want.

Comment: oh my gosh.. happy new year, i have really fun here
    `'31|12|'+(0.2+0.01-2012.21)*-1`

Answer (score 8):

Floating Point Arithmetic is not precise, as some numbers can not be accurately stored so an approximation is used.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Can you handle your `Number`s as integers and then work out the final answer with division?

Comment: great link! Something (else) to read over the holidays...

Comment: @Jessedc - Suppose it will be more interest than listening to the relatives that you only see once a year :-)

Comment: @Jessedc: At least you get 'em :D

Comment: yeah man, thats funny mind jogging!
0.2+1/100=0.21000000000000002
the jingle bells just 0.00000000000000002 more :D
but 
0.2+1/100-0.00000000000000002= yeahh! :-P

Comment: means `( ( 0.2 * 10 ) + 0.1 * 10 ) / 10 == 0.3` 
hurraaaa!

Answer (score 0):

Floatinhg point numbers are stored not precisely in computers - you need to take into account their binary representation. Hence with floating point number arithmetic you get rounding errors.